# Why does this blank game have a leak in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I am completely confused as to why this leaks. After xCode 7.2 was released, the program I was working on started having memory leaks. I've stripped all of the code to the bare minimum and the leak is still here. If anyone knows how to instantiate a GameScene class with an initializer and avoid leaks please let me know. 
Here is the GameViewController:

```
 class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
          let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height))
            let skView = view as! SKView
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsPhysics = true
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
}
// the rest is standard
```

Here is the GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
}
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

}
}
```

Here is what instruments is telling me 
[image]

This tells me that I am creating GameScene in a way that causes some reference look perhaps, but surely there is a way to create a GameScene and have an initializer in place.

Comment: In the nicest possible way, what makes you think there's a leak? Is Instruments telling you that? If so, what exactly is being leaked?

Comment: Thanks, I added a picture and brief explanation of what I can only imaging is happening. When viewing the debug navigator and watching the memory consumption, it steadily increases 0.1 MB/ sec

Comment: Steadily increasing is unusual. So if you leave it alone for 20 minutes it's using 120MB?

Comment: indeed, it will continue, and in the console it will display low memory warnings

Comment: Does it happen in the Xcode SpriteKit template project too?

Comment: I doesn't because the template does not use an initializer for the GameScene

Comment: It seems to me you need to either try removing your custom initializer, or try adding one to Apple's example. If that ends up being the problem, you might need to submit a bug to Apple.

Comment: This is really weird but when I set skView.showPhysics to false, there is no memory leak. I've tried this on the template (after adding an initializer to the GameScene) when I set the value of skView.showPhysics to true, there is a leak.

Comment: I think this issue is solved, but you should still file a radar with Apple.

Comment: will do, thanks for your help

Comment: @C.Greene Can you please post your finding that setting skView.showPhysics to false clears the leak as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:
`skView.showsPhysics = true`